# How to get web service boolean value in Android?

Tags: java, android, web-services

My webservice has two parameters.These unamePI and passPI.I'm sending web service username and password. I getting true value but I can't use this value for verification.How to get web service returned booelan value?

```
  btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               uname=e_name.getText().toString();
               password=e_pass.getText().toString();

                new CallWebService().execute();
               Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
                if(deger=="true"){
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

My AsyncTask:

```
public class CallWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                   getLogin(uname,password);
                return null;
                       }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            }
           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {

           } }
```

getlogin function:

```
 public void getLogin(String uname, String password){
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            PropertyInfo namePI = new PropertyInfo();
            namePI.setName("unamePI");
            namePI.setValue(uname);
            namePI.setType(boolean.class);
            request.addProperty(namePI);

            PropertyInfo pasPI = new PropertyInfo();
            pasPI.setName("passPI");
            pasPI.setValue(password);
            pasPI.setType(boolean.class);
            request.addProperty(pasPI);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            //Set output SOAP object
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            //Create HTTP call object
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            try {
                //Invole web service
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                //Get the response
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                //Assign it to deger static variable
                deger = response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Web Service from returned value:

```
<boolean xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">true</boolean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Boolean` comparision like below.

```
deger = new Boolean(response.toString());

if(deger)
{
   startActivity(intent);
}
else
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
deger = new Boolean(response.toString());
```

Comment: I get value with deger setText and returned true  but if(deger==true){ intent starting } not working

Comment: I assume you chage to this `Boolean deger`, so know the rest of you code is : `Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class); if(deger){startActivity(intent);}else{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}`